# In ReactJS I want to call an onClick function on a button to open another website but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In ReactJS I want to call an onClick function on a button to open another website but it doesn't work. The following excerpt of the code is:

```
import PageButton from "./components/PageButton";

  const openInNewTab = (url) => {
    window.open(url, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
  };
```

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="appNav">
        <div className="my-2 buttonContainer buttonContainerTop">
          <PageButton name={"Home"} isBold={true} />
          <PageButton
            name={"Test"}
            onClick={() => openInNewTab("https://www.bing.com/")}
          />
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
import React from "react";

const PageButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn">
      <span className={props.isBold ? "pageButtonBold hoverBold" : "hoverBold"}>
        {props.name}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageButton;
```

It should open the Webpage when I click on it but it doesn't.

Comment: Is `PageButton` a component you wrote? If so, can you show it?

Comment: I added the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `PageButton` to handle the click, you should forward the click handler down like so:

```
const PageButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn" onClick={props.onClick}>
      <span className={props.isBold ? "pageButtonBold hoverBold" : "hoverBold"}>{props.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageButton;
```

Also, I would suggest you transform the `div` to `button` as it's the right element for handling clicks.

Comment: It instantly worked! Thanks a lot. Id give you an upvote if I could

Comment: Glad it did. Yeah, you would need 15 reputations to upvote. Though you could accept the answer by clicking on the check button next to it. This will guide others. –

Answer (score 0):

can you use tag a inside the button like this

```
<button .... > <a href="..." target="_blank"> text<a/> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

At `PageButton` component, you need to add `click event` for `Warpper`.

```
const PageButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn" onClick={props.onClick}>
      <span className={props.isBold ? "pageButtonBold hoverBold" : "hoverBold"}>
        {props.name}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageButton;
```